# Custom Validation and error message for Custom Select

Tags: javascript, html, css, validation

```
function setError(input, message) {
  const form = input.parentElement;
  const small = form.querySelector('small');
  small.innerText = message;
  form.className = 'inputfield error';
}

function setSuccess(input) {
  const form = input.parentElement;
  form.className = 'inputfield success';
}
```

Here is my JavaScript code for setting error or success to the input fields. It is working fine for the inputs.

but when I am trying to apply the same code for custom select boxes it is not working. I am new to web development so any sort of help would be appreciated.

reference Input Field Code :

```
  <div class="inputfield">
    <label>NID</label>
    <input type="text" value="" class="input" id="nid" onkeyup="checkNid()">
    <small>Error Message</small>
  </div>
```

reference Custom Select Code :

```
  <div class="inputfield">
      <label>Gender</label>
      <div class="custom_select">
        <select name="gender" id="gender">
          <option value="">Select</option>
          <option value="male">Male</option>
          <option value="female">Female</option>
          <option value="Others">Others</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <small>Error Message</small>
    </div>
```

Here is the output. I am expecting the same sort of error message for the select fields too:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pea5D.png)

Answer (score 0):

Replace your reference Custom Select Code  with this:

```
<div>
  <label>Gender</label>
  <div class="inputfield custom_select">
    <select name="gender" id="gender">
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <option value="male">Male</option>
      <option value="female">Female</option>
      <option value="Others">Others</option>
    </select>
     <small>Error Message</small>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you had shared your CSS file, I would have suggested how to style it better.

Answer (score 0):

```
 .wrapper .form .inputfield .custom_select {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 37px;
}

.wrapper .form .inputfield .custom_select:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  right: 10px;
  border: 8px solid;
  border-color: #d5dbd9 transparent transparent transparent;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.wrapper .form .inputfield .custom_select select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  outline: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 0px;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #d5dbd9;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

helere is the css for the custom selection

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).